# Should this get error?

Tags: typescript

Should it compile ?
It passes undefined to this.g but it expects a number.

```
class A {
    x: number | undefined;

    f() {
        this.x = 1;
        this.h();
        this.g(this.x);
    }

    g(q: number) { }

    h() { this.x = undefined; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is correct, as for [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

> By default **null** and **undefined** are subtypes of all other types. That
>   means you can assign **null** and **undefined** to something like **number**.

In fact, declaring x as **number | undefined** or simply **number** is equivalent.

**UPDATE:**

As @AlekseyL pointed out, this behavior can be changed by setting the  `--strictNullChecks` compiler option to `true` (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

> In strict null checking mode, the null and undefined values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and any (the one exception being that undefined is also assignable to void).

Comment: This is correct if _strictNullChecks_ mode is not enabled.

Comment: @AlekseyL. thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately even with _strictNullChecks_, in this specific case, compiler will not throw an error as it can't infer (at least for now) that value was set to `undefined` in `h()`

Comment: @AlekseyL. With `--strictNullChecks` enabled the compiler will raise an error on the assignment `this.x = undefined`, won't it? At least a quick check with http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20f()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.h()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.g(this.x)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20g(q%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20h()%20%7B%20this.x%20%3D%20undefined%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D proves that.

Comment: If you'll define `x: number | undefined;` as in example it will not. And we're looking for error here `this.g(this.x)`